# How can I get static html page using post method by springboot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In the springboot, when I get resource by post method, I will receive 'Request method 'POST' not supported', I've konwn how to solve it in the spring mvc, I can add support methods 'POST' in ResourceHttpRequestHandler, but I don't konw how to solve it in the springboot, so hope someone to sovle my problem, thanks very much.

Comment: please give what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, here is my solution.

```
@PostConstruct
public void addSupportType() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean("resourceHandlerMapping", SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.class);
    Map<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler> urlMap = (Map<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler>) handlerMapping.getUrlMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ResourceHttpRequestHandler> entry : urlMap.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().setSupportedMethods("GET", "POST");
    }

}
```